# How to replace text without changing quoted string with regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace

```
$this->input->post("product_name");
```

with

```
$post_data["product_name"];
```

I want to use notepad++ regex, but I couldn't find proper solution

In find --> `$this->input->post("[\*w\]");`
In replace --> `$post_data["$1"];`

but its not working

Comment: You are referencing a matching group ($1) that you did not create. Pu parenthesis outside the *w to match that word and pass it to the replace stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$this->input->post("[\*w\]");` pattern does not work because:

- `$` is a special char matching the end of a line, you need to use `\$` to match it as a literal char
- `[\*w'\]` is a malformed pattern as there is no matching unescaped `]` for the `[` that opens a character class. Also, `w` just matches `w`, not any letter, digit or underscore, `\w` does that.

You may use

**Find What**: `\$this->input->post\("(\w*)"\);` 
**Replace With**: `$post_data["$1"];`

If there can be any char inside double quotes use `.*?` instead of `\w*`:

**Find What**: `\$this->input->post\("(.*?)"\);`

[Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C%24this-%3Einput-%3Epost%5C(%22(%5Cw*)%22%5C)%3B):

[image]

NPP test:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern to match desired text `\$this->input->post\(("[^"]+")\);`

And replace it with pattern `\$post_data\[\1\]`

Explanation:

`\$this->input->post` - matach `$this->input->post` literally

`\(("[^"]+")\);` - match `(`literally, then match double quates and everything between them with `"[^"]+"` and store inside first capturing group, then match `);` literally

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- To replace

`$this->input->post("product_name");`

by

`$post_data["product_name"];`

do replace, with regex activated

`this->input->post\("(.*)"\);`

by

`post_data\["\1"\];`

- The `\x` with x a number, corresponds to the x-th match catched with the parenthesis. Here we catch any character inside `this->input->post(XXXX);`
- Don't forget to escape special character with `\`.
  Your special characters were `[]()`